# Transfer call and recording

Tags: php, voicexml, vonage

Can someone explain how can I send transfer call record to my server? Im using Nexmo.

Here is what I have for `answer_url` parameter:

```
<vxml version = "2.1">
    <form id="CallTransfer">
        <block>
            <prompt>Hello</prompt>
        </block>
        <transfer name="MyCall" dest="tel:+'.$number.'" bridge="true" connecttimeout="20s"/>
        <record name="recording" beep="false" finalsilence="3s" maxtime="240s">
            <catch event="connection.disconnect.hangup">
                <submit next="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/api/save_call/'.$history_id.'" method="post" namelist="recording" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
            </catch>
            <filled>
                <submit next="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/api/save_call/'.$history_id.'" method="post" namelist="recording" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
            </filled>
        </record>
    </form>                
</vxml>
```

But its send empty $_FILES array on `/api/save_call`.

Also, I have a question, is it possible to get call record starting when first abonent picked up the phone and ending when second is hangup?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do call recording and I do not believe this method will work.  All examples of call recording use CCXML.  Here is one example [ http://help.voxeo.com/go/help/xml.ccxml.audio.recording ].  I am not sure if Nexmo supports CCXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible to record a transfer using native VXML. As [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201128/transfer-call-and-recording#comment43014911_27201128) points out, that just not something VXML supports.

We (I work at Nexmo) know there are use cases that require that support, and it is something we're working on.